# Electron works unexpectedly with updating component's style

Tags: javascript, electron

The code below works perfectly in browser, but not in Electron env.

```
function listenFileInput() {
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', ev => {
    startProgress();

    const file = ev.target.files[0];
    if (!file) return clearProgress();

    loadImage(file);
  });
}

function loadImage(file) {
  const image = new Image();

  image.onload = function() {
    const src = cropImage(this);
    cardImage.src = src;
    clearProgress();
  };

  image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
}


function startProgress() {
  fileBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  fileInput.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  progress.style.display = 'flex';
}

function clearProgress() {
  fileBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  fileInput.removeAttribute('disabled');
  progress.style.display = 'none';
}
```

In Electron env, when the file is loaded, the progress doesn't show up.

After do some tests, I found some interesting phenomenon:

1. If I comment the `image.onload = function() {...}` block, it works properly.
2. If I add `alert()` in `onChange` event callback or `startProgress` function, after alerting, the progress appears as expected.
3. If I comment `clearProgress();` in `image.onload` callback, after the image was loaded, the progress appears.

So, it seems that the `setAttribute` and `style.display` didn't work (or Electron didn't re-render the page) until the image was loaded, unless there's an alert disturbs the process.

I've pushed the complete code to [GitHub](https://github.com/brickyang/reading-card-generator/tree/progress) (/lib/file.js).